# Some of the values of $f(x)$ are different from those derived by Table

Tags: table

It is known that there are the following functions:

```
f[x_] := x - 1/2 + 1/Pi Sum[Sin[2 Pi k x]/k, {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

Tests on some of the values taken.

```
f[0] // Chop
f[0.5] // Chop
f[1] // Chop
f[1.5] // Chop
f[2] // Chop
```

> -(1/2), 0, 1/2, 1., 3/2

But with `Table`, the result will be different.

```
Table[f[x], {x, 0, 2, 0.5}] // Chop
```

> {-0.5, 0, 0, 1., 1.}

It is clear that the values of the function at $x=1$ and $x=2$ cannot correspond, why is that?

Comment: It comes from this `Sum[Sin[2 Pi k x]/k, {k, 1, Infinity}]`, here is screen shot to illustrate  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD0FU.png)   Seems to have caused some issue here. Need more investigation to find exactly why. But as a general rule, Try to avoid non exact numbers when doing exact calculations.

Comment: The results in the picture shocked me, first time I've had this problem @Nasser.

Comment: Yes, seems to be some numerical issue in the sum you have. Could be a bug. But need more looking into it to know exactly why it happened. (but as I said, to be safe, avoid non-exact numbers in exact calculations).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function is discontinuous on the integers, and so it matters exactly where you are evaluating it. Numerical is not equal to analytical evaluation for discontinuous functions.

```
f[x_] = x - 1/2 + 1/π Sum[Sin[2 π k x]/k, {k, 1, ∞}]
(*    -1/2 + x + (I (Log[1 - E^(2 I π x)] - Log[E^(-2 I π x) (-1 + E^(2 I π x))]))/(2 π)    *)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Show the discontinuity at $x=2$ for example:

```
Limit[f[x], x -> 2, Direction -> "FromBelow"]
(*    1    *)

Limit[f[x], x -> 2, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
(*    2    *)
```

So, numerically, you may get 1, 2, or their average 1.5 depending on details.